# Admob How to set alpha (opacity) of GADBannerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, alpha

Is it possible to set the alpha channel of GADBannerView on iOS?

I was able to set it with the old sdk. The latest sdk also supports alpha (I use alpha animation). But in iOS,   `_bannerView.alpha = 0.9;` does not work anymore.

I just wanna make the ads less disturbing.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as an Android question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
`_bannerView.layer.opacity = 0.1;`

It works for me